# Counting Occurrences Across Dataframe Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I've found responses close to this but nothing that quite does the trick. I have a data table that looks like so:

```
ID          DATE
74180       11/07/2000
74180       11/04/2008
81337       11/04/2008
81337       11/02/2010
82557       11/07/2000
82557       11/05/2002
82557       11/02/2004
82557       11/04/2008
82557       11/06/2012
82901       11/07/2000
82901       11/05/2002
82901       11/02/2004
82901       11/04/2008
82901       11/06/2012
82901       11/04/2014
83103       11/04/2008
83103       11/02/2010
83103       11/06/2012
83103       11/04/2014
```

I'd like to convert this so that each ID occupies a single row and the various dates represented as binary columns ie:

```
ID        11/07/2000   11/05/2002   11/02/2004 ...
74180     1              0           0 
81337     0              0           0
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, recreating your DataFrame:

```
ID = [74180,74180,81337,81337,82557,82557,82557,82557,82557,82901,82901,82901,82901,82901,82901,83103,83103,83103,83103]
DATE = ['2000-11-07','2008-11-04','2008-11-04','2010-11-02','2000-11-07','2002-11-05','2004-11-02','2008-11-04','2012-11-06','2000-11-7','2002-11-05','2004-11-02','2008-11-04','2012-11-06','2014-11-04','2008-11-04','2010-11-02','2012-11-06','2014-11-04']
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':ID, 'DATE':DATE})
```

The actual processing:

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('ID')['DATE'])
df2.reset_index().groupby('ID').sum()
```

Output:

```
       2000-11-07  2000-11-7  2002-11-05  2004-11-02  2008-11-04 ...
ID
74180         1.0        0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0 ...
81337         0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0 ...
82557         1.0        0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0 ...
82901         0.0        1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0 ...
83103         0.0        0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0 ...
```

Comment: This certainly seems close but for some reason my code is yielding the desired result. I still retain multiple rows for each 'ID'.

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('ID')['DATE'])
df2.reset_index().groupby('ID').sum()

I see no mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
df.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
pd.get_dummies(df.loc[:, 'DATE']).groupby(level='ID').sum()

       2000-11-07  2002-11-05  2004-11-02  2008-11-04  2010-11-02  2012-11-06  \
ID                                                                              
74180         1.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         0.0         0.0   
81337         0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         1.0         0.0   
82557         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         1.0   
82901         1.0         1.0         1.0         1.0         0.0         1.0   
83103         0.0         0.0         0.0         1.0         1.0         1.0   

       2014-11-04  
ID                 
74180         0.0  
81337         0.0  
82557         0.0  
82901         1.0  
83103         1.0
```

Comment: Lovely, this solves the first problem. Now I need to collapse them into a single row based on ID.